# Как правильно сгенерировать меню в YII?

Tags: меню, php, yii

С `YII` недавно столкнулся. в шаблоне `main.php` нужно сделать список, в который должны выгружаться все данные строк определенной таблицы. Как получить из базы данные и вывести их я в принципе уже знаю, но как правильно сгенерировать такое меню? Таки, мне кажется, есть специальный логичный и правильный вариант.

Comment: ссылки на статьи и параграфы в мануалах приветствуются (сам не нашел), как приветствуются и общая информация по меню в yii

Comment: я короче сделал в Controller public метод buildLeftMenu() который возвращает массив с данными для виджета CMenu. main.php просто вызывает его внутри виджета меню. хорошо ли так делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такой виджет в Yii, называется CMenu: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMenu

В контроллере (например Controller) создаёте публичный метод, который будет возвращать массив с наименования пунктов:

```
public function getMenuItems() {
   $dbQuery = Menu::model()->findAll(); //Если используете ActiveRecord
   $menuItems = array();

   foreach($dbQuery as $item) {
      $menuItems[] = array('label'=>$item->name, 'url'=>array(''));
   }
   return $menuItems;
}
```

В макете используете полученный массив в качестве параметра в виджете:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
    'items'=>$this->getMenuItems(),
));
```

Таким методом можно вытянуть из БД и другие данные, например url'ы.

Как я понял, Вы сделали выборку по такому же принципу. Но детали не уточнили, поэтому я расписал весь процесс.

Похожий вопрос обсуждался тут: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/30072-cmenu-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B4/

Comment: да, я именно так и сделал. спасибо